Enabling category groups audit and auditAll on all key vaults
I am looking at automating the process of enabling audit and audit all on all key vaults, there is a diagnostic setting in place for all the vaults, what's left to do is enabling audit and allLogs for the vaults. I have checked Azure policies if there is a policy to see if there is a remediation plan in place that can be used to automate the process. I could not find any.
I then started the process of writing the script below.
# Connect to Azure
Connect-AzAccount

# Get all Azure subscriptions
$subscription = Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName 'my-sub'

# $subscription = Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId  # Use this line if filtering by subscription ID

if ($subscription -eq $null) {
    Write-Output "Subscription not found."
    exit
}

# Set the current subscription context
Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $subscription.Id


# Array to hold key vaults without diagnostic settings
$noDiagnosticSettingsKeyVaults = @()
# Array to hold key vaults with updated audit log settings
$updatedAuditLogSettingsKeyVaults = @()

# Get all Key Vaults in the specified subscription
$keyVaults = Get-AzKeyVault -VaultName 'kv-autom-dev-001'

foreach ($keyVault in $keyVaults) {
    # Get the diagnostic settings for the current Key Vault
    $diagnosticSettings = Get-AzDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId $keyVault.ResourceId

    if ($diagnosticSettings.Count -eq 0) {
        # If there are no diagnostic settings, add the key vault to the array
        $noDiagnosticSettingsKeyVaults += [PSCustomObject]@{
            KeyVaultName  = $keyVault.VaultName
            ResourceGroup = $keyVault.ResourceGroupName
            Subscription  = $subscription.Name
        }
    } else {
        # If diagnostic settings exist, ensure audit log settings are configured
        $logSettings = @()
        $logSettings += New-AzDiagnosticSettingLogSettingsObject -Enabled $true -Category "AuditEvent"
        $logSettings += New-AzDiagnosticSettingLogSettingsObject -Enabled $true -Category "allLogs"

        # Configure the diagnostic settings with the new log settings
        Set-AzDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId $keyVault.ResourceId -Name $diagnosticSettings.Name -Log $logSettings -Enabled $true

        # Add the key vault to the updated audit log settings array
        $updatedAuditLogSettingsKeyVaults += [PSCustomObject]@{
            KeyVaultName  = $keyVault.VaultName
            ResourceGroup = $keyVault.ResourceGroupName
            Subscription  = $subscription.Name
        }
    }
}

I was getting the error
ARNING: Set-AzDiagnosticSetting is not found. The most similar Azure PowerShell commands are: Get-AzDiagnosticSetting New-AzDiagnosticSetting Set-AzDiagnosticSetting: The term 'Set-AzDiagnosticSetting' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program

Any update on the issue?

Initially by using the same script I got the same error:

To enable audit and allLogs for the key vaults, make use of below PowerShell script:
# Connect to Azure
Connect-AzAccount

# Get the desired Azure subscription
$subscription = Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName 'SubName'

if ($subscription -eq $null) {
   Write-Output "Subscription not found."
   exit
}

# Set the current subscription context
Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $subscription.Id

# Replace this with your actual workspace ID
$workspaceId = "/subscriptions/xxx/resourcegroups/xxx/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/xxx"

# Create the Log settings object with supported categories
$logSettings = @()
$logSettings += New-AzDiagnosticSettingLogSettingsObject -Enabled $true -CategoryGroup "Audit"
$logSettings += New-AzDiagnosticSettingLogSettingsObject -Enabled $true -CategoryGroup "AllLogs"

# Get all Key Vaults in the specified subscription
$keyVaults = Get-AzKeyVault

# Keep track of updated Key Vaults
$updatedKeyVaults = @()

foreach ($keyVault in $keyVaults) {
   # Check existing diagnostic settings for the Key Vault
   $existingSettings = Get-AzDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId $keyVault.ResourceId -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

   if ($existingSettings) {
       # If diagnostic settings exist, update them
       New-AzDiagnosticSetting -Name $existingSettings.Name `
                               -ResourceId $keyVault.ResourceId `
                               -Log $logSettings `
                               -WorkspaceId $workspaceId
       $updatedKeyVaults += $keyVault.VaultName
   } else {
       # If diagnostic settings do not exist, create them
       New-AzDiagnosticSetting -Name "DiagnosticSetting" `
                               -ResourceId $keyVault.ResourceId `
                               -Log $logSettings `
                               -WorkspaceId $workspaceId
       $updatedKeyVaults += $keyVault.VaultName
   }
}

# Output the results with names of updated Key Vaults
if ($updatedKeyVaults.Count -gt 0) {
   Write-Output "Diagnostic settings have been applied to the following Key Vaults:"
   $updatedKeyVaults | ForEach-Object { Write-Output $_ }
} else {
   Write-Output "No Key Vaults were updated."
}


The diagnostic setting added successfully:

For existing diagnostic setting vaults also the Logs will be enabled.
Reference:
Create diagnostic settings in Azure Monitor - Azure Monitor | Microsoft
